# Setting up CreateBundle - Document is not managed and has no id

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, createjs

I'm trying to set up and make working the [CreateBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/create/introduction.html#installation) but ran into this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Document is not managed and has no id: Ist1\PageBundle\Entity\Page@0000000019ffdaf900007f0da4032c17") in src/Ist1/PageBundle/Resources/views/Page/show.html.twig at line 18.
```

I've got a regular doctrine entity (Page), don't know if needed something else or ...? All I want is to be able to use the in-place editor for my Page entity.

rdf-mappings/Ist1.PageBundle.Entity.Page.xml:

```
<type xmlns:schema="http://schema.org/" typeof="schema:Page">
<children>
    <property property="schema:content" identifier="content"/>
</children>
```

The exception is thrown in the Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\UnitOfWork class, as there is no key/value in the documentIds array for my page entity ...

```
if (empty($this->documentIds[$oid])) {
...
```

Comment: No code, no details?.. hard to help.

Comment: I simply went through the documentation... What details should I provide?

Comment: Think I'm going to revert and leave this nonsense ... why do I have to have this PHPCR at all?? I just want to use the editor and thats it!